# How do I solve this simultaneous equation involving trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$x = a_1\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + a_2\cos(\theta_1)$

$y = a_1\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + a_2\sin(\theta_1)$

Solve for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$,they are angles for a robot, where $x$ and $y$ are the position. I want to get the angles given a position, I know there will be multiple solutions. I've attempted to use Wolfram Alpha to no avail.

Accidentally mistyped the equation, have updated.

Comment: All coeficients are $a_2$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try to use unambiguous titles in your posts so if people have the same question in the future it will be easier to find. Also, you are more likely to receive help if you add what your current ideas/attempts have been so far

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran thank's for pointing that out.

Comment: @VictoriaM will do in the future, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [sum to product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to write
$$ \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1)=2\cos\left(\frac {2\theta_1+\theta_2}2\right)\cos\left(\frac {\theta_2}2\right)\\
 \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \sin(\theta_1)=2\sin\left(\frac {2\theta_1+\theta_2}2\right)\cos\left(\frac {\theta_2}2\right)\\
\frac yx=\tan\left(\frac {2\theta_1+\theta_2}2\right)\\
2\theta_1+\theta_2=\arctan \frac {2y}x\\
\frac {x^2+y^2}{a_2^2}=\cos^2\left(\frac {\theta_2}2\right)\\
\theta_2=2\arccos \sqrt{\frac {x^2+y^2}{a_2^2}}$$

Added:  with the $a$s not being the same, the above doesn't work.  You can still write $\sin = \pm \sqrt {1-\cos^2}$ to get to two equations in two unknowns, $\cos \theta_1$ and $\cos (\theta_1+\theta_2)$.  It will be messier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I mistyped the original question, this method doesn't work anymore right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: sum to product formula will drastically simplify the problem. Then make use of $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ to solve for $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2/2)$. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equations 
$$x = a_1\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + a_2\cos(\theta_1)\tag 1$$
$$y = a_1\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + a_2\sin(\theta_1)\tag 2$$ first let $\theta_3=\theta_1 + \theta_2$ and rewrite the equations as
$$a_1\cos(\theta_3)=a_2\cos(\theta_1)-x$$
$$a_1\sin(\theta_3)=a_2\sin(\theta_1)-y$$ and square to get
$$a_1^2=(a_2\cos(\theta_1)-x)^2+(a_2\sin(\theta_1)-y)^2$$ that is to say
$$x \sin (\theta_1)+y \cos (\theta_1)=\frac{x^2+y^2+a_2^2-a_1^2}{2 a_2}=k$$
Use the tangent half-angle subsitution $t=\tan \left(\frac{\theta_1 }{2}\right)$ to get the quadratic in $t$
$$ (k+y)t^2-2  xt+(k-y)=0\implies t=\, ??? \implies \theta_1=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$$ Go back to $(1)$ or $(2)$ to get $\theta_2$